# How do I say "be one" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How do you say "be one" in Latin?

As an example, Marcus Aurelius famously states (along the lines of) "Stop asking what a good man should be - be one."

I don't think it can be a direct translation; to begin with, I don't think "unum" in Latin carries the same possible pronoun meaning as "one" in English, although I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I did some searching, and the quote originally in Greek, from *M. Antonius Imperator Ad Se Ipsum, 10.16*

> Μηκέθ̓ ὅλως περὶ τοῦ οἷόν τινα εἶναι τὸν ἀγαθὸν ἄνδρα διαλέγεσθαι, ἀλλὰ εἶναι τοιοῦτον.

To match the Greek—particularly *τοιοῦτον*—you'd use *talis*, meaning "such", to mean "one". I think this would be the option for most cases like this one. As for "be", strictly speaking the singular imperative is "es", and the plural "este". This makes "be one" *es talis* (speaking to one person) or *este talis* (speaking to multiple people, where *talis* is still singular because it agrees with an implied singular subject.)

I think the Greek uses an infinitive construction, viable in Latin as well. It says something like "Don't decide anymore what makes a good man, but instead to be one". Keep in mind, I don't actually know Greek, but in that scenario "to be one" would be in Latin *esse talem*.

Comment: I might suggest *esto* for the imperative here, since *es talis* might well be interpreted to mean 'you are one'.